# configuration for pdo and postgresql

Tags: php, pdo, postgresql-9.1

I'm using postgreSQL 9.1 with postGIS 2.0 .Also Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13. I'm trying to set PHP's PDO for postgreSQL. I also use Windows 7.
According to this [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) I am ok, I checked my php.ini and I found this line `extension=php_pgsql.dll`

But according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.configuration.php) (runtime configuration) I have to set a dsn in my php.ini. I dont actually get what I have to do. And why. I try to write something like `pdo.dsn.'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432'`, in php.ini and then I restarted the Apache.

After that I created a new php file to test PDO.
This is the code

```
    try {  
      $DBH = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=0000;dbname=blah;user=blah;password=blah");  
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );  

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo" sorry man! ";
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    } 
$name="frouto";
$STH = $DBH -> prepare("SELECT * FROM controller WHERE c_name LIKE :name;");
$STH->bindParam(':name', $name);

$STH->execute();
$result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Just really simple to test PDO. This does not work at all. Nor an exception error is printed. I guess runtime configuration is wrong. And dsn is also wrong. What I have to do to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that postgres is running on your localhost.

Second, make sure you can connect to postgres: telnet localhost 5432

Third, Postgres typically runs on port 5432. Your code is connecting on 0000.

The DSN is the (only) argument in your PDO creation:

```
$DBH = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;port=0000;dbname=blah;user=blah;password=blah");
```

i.e.

```
$dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost;port=0000;dbname=blah;user=blah;password=blah";
$DBH = new PDO($dsn);
```

check each of these steps, and ask again how to resolve if one of them fails and you are unable to figure that step out.

Comment: @ Zak Hi. Yes I checked and runs OK. I can connect by using `pg_connect` so I guess I am OK. And yes, the actuall port is 5432, I just chose to "hide" that , along with username, passowrd etc. So, just to clarify, I dont have to add anything in my php.ini file? Then what's the problem? I dont get it

Comment: can you also run your query using the relevant login credentials from the command line? Ensure you have permission to run the query.

Comment: also, do a print_r on $results.. what does that say?

Comment: I re-edit my connection by rewriting the "try" part as follow $dsn= "pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=blah;user=blah;password=blah"; $DBH = new PDO($dsn); $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ); echo"conn ok"; . I also used this print_r($STH);. The "try" part prints "conn ok" but the print_r and the query still dont work.